# JSF - Difference in getting bean instance

Tags: jsf

HI,

There are many ways to get the bean instances from the JSF context. In the following two way:

```
Bean bean = (Bean) request.getAttribute("beanName");
```

and

```
FacesUtils.getManagedBean("beanName");
```

What is the difference in above two ways. In which case we have to use either ways. Please clarify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first if you're not inside the JSF context (aka the `FacesContext`), e.g. inside a servlet. The second way is unclear since `FacesUtils` is not part of standard JSF implementation (it's likely a homegrown or 3rd party library). But if it grabs it by the `FacesContext`, then it works only when you're already inside the JSF context (i.e. inside a JSF managed bean).

Comment: Yes. You are correct. It looks like FacesUtils not part of the JSF implementation.

Comment: OK, do you have any doubts with regard to the answer?